# Android How to programmatically press the back button

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to programmatically press the back button.
I have a small code that opens a tab in the Chrome browser.
After some time, if you press the back button on the phone with your hands, the open tab will close and my application will activate.
How can I implement this programmatically?
If you use this.onBackPressed(), then it will apply to my application will not lead to the desired result.
Here is the code on Kotlin with which I open the tab:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.google.ru/")
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome")
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: I think you can't. Since you've opened chrome, your app is no longer in charge of what's happening, chrome is. So you won't be able simulate user input on the chrome app. Note : If i'm wrong and you can, I strongly recommend you to not do that. It won't be user-friendly/user-understandable to have chrome closing and switching back to your app whitout it being triggered by the user himself.

Comment: Hi, i didn't get what you want to do. you want to close the app after opening chrome so the user can't get back to the application ? am i get that right ?

Comment: You could add a ``WebView`` *inside your app* and display a webpage for a certain amount of time - if you open *a different app* you don't really have any control over it, beyond any options it allows you to pass (like the URL you're sending here). And I doubt Chrome provides the ability to create the kind of behaviour you want

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible for what I hope are obvious security reasons. Please explain _why_ you think you need to control closing the user's apps for them and maybe you can get help achieving your ultimate goal.

Comment: Hello, I need to programmatically close the opened tab in the browser. Since chrome won't let me close it, I thought I could programmatically press the back button. But so that it does not apply to my application, but as if the user clicked it. Another option, I saw a program somewhere that repeats tapping on the touchscreen and thought that it was possible to simulate clicking and thus close the tab.
Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: "I need to programmatically close the opened tab in the browser." - No, you don't. That's malware behavior. Again _why_ do you think you need to close the user's tab for them? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: This clearly looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you please explain why you think you should close the tab ?